# I have problems about my fov visualization script in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried writing some code to visualize the field of view for a top-down shooter game.
I sent rays around my character and collected info whether that ray hits or not.
I stored these points in a list and tried meshing triangles.
My problem started right there. If rays don't hit an obstacle there is no problem. It can create meshes. But if rays hit an obstacle, it cant create triangles. It just creates weird things around my character.

[image]

and there is my code :

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class fieldOfView : MonoBehaviour {

public float viewDistance;
public LayerMask obstacleMask;
public float viewAngle;
public float meshResolution;
public MeshFilter viewMeshFilter;
public Mesh viewMesh;

private void Start()
{
    viewMesh = new Mesh();
    viewMesh.name = "View Mesh";
    viewMeshFilter.mesh = viewMesh;
}

private void Update()
{
    DrawFieldOfView();
}
Vector3 DirFromAngle(float angle)
{
    angle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angle), 0, Mathf.Cos(angle));
}

void DrawFieldOfView()
{
    int stepCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(viewAngle / meshResolution);
    List<Vector3> viewPoints = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> hitPoints = new List<Vector3>();



    RaycastHit hit;

    for(int i = 0; i <= stepCount; i++)
    {
        float angle = transform.eulerAngles.y +i * meshResolution;
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,DirFromAngle(angle),out hit, obstacleMask))
        {
            viewPoints.Add(hit.point);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
            hitPoints.Add(hit.point);
        }
        else
        {
            viewPoints.Add(transform.position + DirFromAngle(angle) * viewDistance);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + DirFromAngle(angle) * viewDistance);
        }
    }

    int vertexCount = viewPoints.Count + 1;

    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vertexCount];
    int[] triangles = new int[(vertexCount - 2) * 3];

    vertices[0] = Vector3.zero;

    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount-1; i++)
    {
        vertices[i + 1] = viewPoints[i];
        if (i < vertexCount - 2)
        {
            triangles[i * 3] = 0;
            triangles[i * 3 + 1] = i + 1;
            triangles[i * 3 + 2] = i + 2;
        }
    }
    viewMesh.Clear();
    viewMesh.vertices = vertices;
    viewMesh.triangles = triangles;
    viewMesh.RecalculateNormals();



}
}
```

Comment: That is strange.. Does it help if you do viewPoints.Add(transform.position + DirFromAngle(angle) * hit.distance) ?

Comment: Nope. I've tried this solution too . But again, it rendered weird shapes around my cube.